# Railsで1:多のモデルを消す際にエラーが出る。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bs, dependent: :destroy
end

#  a_id :integer          not null
class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
end
```

このようなモデルがある時に、A.first.deleteを実行すると

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "as" WHERE "as"."id" = ?
```

というエラーが出ます。
自分の推測では外部キーに関連するエラーのようですが、そういったエラーが出ないようするために、dependentを設定したつもりでした。
なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？またどうやって解決すれば良いでしょうか？

ご回答いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete`の代わりに`destroy`を使ってください。

ActiveRecordには

- コールバックやバリデーションが動く「通常の」メソッド
- コールバックやバリデーションが動かないメソッド

があります。`destroy`は前者、`delete`は後者です。

Comment: そのような違いがあったのですね。修正したら動きました。ご返信ありがとうございました。